# Font corruption every time Chromium snap updates?

Tags: fonts, chromium

I have the Chromium snap installed on 20.04 through Software Center. Every time the snaps gets updated, I can’t use any kind of file upload dialog while browsing because the text is entirely replaced by Unicode squares until I manually flush and rebuild the font cache. Is there any way to avoid having to do this every time something changes with Chromium?

Comment: @heynnema the standard binary/.deb version installs the snap; so I don't see what you comment was about sorry (that way for 19.10 & 20.04).  FYI: Brian Smith, a picture may have also helped us understand your issue.

Comment: Hmmm. Chromuim uses whatever fonts are on your system. Other Snap users don't have this problem, so I wonder what's wrong with your fonts.

Comment: Are you using a third-party form of Chromium? Chromium is generally very secure and they manage their updates and codes well, it could be corrupted if it is from third party sources, or if you are updating from a third-party Snap (check your update repos with the command: sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list